# gnuplot help points don't match equation

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting a function with points.  But they don't match up. Here's my script.

```
set terminal svg size 600, 320 font 'Arial,10'
set xlabel 'Amount'
set ylabel 'Response'
set grid
set xrange [*:*]
set yrange [*:*]
set samples (100 - 1)/1 + 1
f(x) = -.00460160431126948 + (x * .159907884344821) + ((x**2) * 0)
plot f(x) with lines lw 3 linecolor rgb 'purple' notitle, '-' with points ls 7 linecolor rgb 'orange' notitle
0 13.33
.2 582.23333
1 2746.95
10 26147.62333
50 131314.39667
75.000001875 192126.03
100 259905.49333
e
```

[image]

Comment: Why should the points fit on `f(x)`?  From where and how did you get the the numeric values of `f(x)`? And what should this be `set samples (100 - 1)/1 + 1`? Shorter `set samples 100` which is already the default.

Comment: The data comes from a scientific instrument.  The points are correct, so the equation must be wrong.  Regarding "set samples"  I was grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot has the option to fit a function to some data (check `help fit`).

If you have a quadratic function, e.g. `f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c`, you can find `a,b,c` which fit your data best. It seems your values `a,b,c` are completely off.

**Script:**

```
### fitting
reset session

$Data <<EOD
  0                 13.33
  0.2              582.23333
  1               2746.95
 10              26147.62333
 50             131314.39667
 75.000001875   192126.03
100             259905.49333
EOD

f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c
set fit nolog
fit f(x) $Data u 1:2 via a,b,c

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 lc "orange", \
     f(x) w l lw 3 lc "purple"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = -0.0123093       +/- 0.6177       (5018%)
b               = 2589.97          +/- 58.01        (2.24%)
c               = 186.967          +/- 790.1        (422.6%)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The points are definitely off.  I need to figure out why they don't match the equation.